# Problemas com geração de arquivo Excel (.xlsx) com a biblioteca PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Estou trabalhando em um projeto em que necessito gerar arquivos do Excel com informações do banco (relatórios).

Consegui fazer isso com a biblioteca PhpSpreadsheet, porém o arquivo é salvo no servidor, e quando eu adiciono os cabeçalhos para forçar o download do arquivo, ele vem corrompido. Se tiro os cabeçalhos gera normalmente.

Os cabeçalhos que estou usando:

```php
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($sheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```